# Bind ng2-nvd3 chart with component in Angular 2 using dispatch

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, charts, angular, ng2-nvd3

I'm need to update data in chart and keep user configuration of chart 
(multiBarChart, stacked option).

Here is my component

```
...
<nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>
...

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(nvD3) nvD3: nvD3;
stream$: Observable<Line[]>;
stacked: boolean;
data: any[];
options: any;
constructor(private _chart: ChartService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.stream$ = this._chart.stream$;
    this.data = [];
    this.stacked = false;
    .debounceTime(500)
    .subscribe(
        counter => {
            this.nvD3.options.chart.stacked = this.stacked;
            this.data = counter;
            console.log("cahrtData emitted");
            this.nvD3.chart.update();
        }
    );
    this.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'multiBarChart',
                height: 450,
                margin: {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 50,
                    left: 55
                },
                dispatch: {
                    stateChange: function(e) { 
                           console.log('stateChange')
                           this.stacked = e.stacked;
                    }
                },
                "stacked": false,
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

}

Seems that this.stacked in option have nothing to do with this.staked in component.
So my question is how to bind stateChange with component variable in proper way?

Comment: where is (in which file) your options `this.options = {` located?

Comment: options and data and stacked located in dashboard component

Comment: export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(nvD3) nvD3: nvD3;
    steam$: Observable<Line[]>;
    stacked: boolean;
    data: any[];
    options: any;
    constructor(private _chart: ChartService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
  this.stream$ = this._chart.stream$;
     this.data = [];
     this.stacked = false;
  this.stream$
  ...
  this.options = {
  ...
  }
 }
}